# Deleting an object in Realm and keeping tableview in sync

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Have two basic viewControllers: a tableView and a detailView.

I am subscribing to notification to reload the tableView if the data is modified. I can modify a record from the detailViewController, and the changes get reflected. Even delete a record from the tableView, and it works.

BUT I would also like to add a delete button on the detailView, but then the viewController and Realm gets out of sync and crashes. 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'. The next time I load the app the record is deleted so it works.

How can I delete an object in a different viewController and keep the tablieView controller updated?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var token:NotificationToken?
    var expenses: Results<Expense> {
    get {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return realm.objects(Expense.self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        token = realm.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] notification, realm in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

class DetailViewController {
     func deleteButtonTapped() {
         let realm = try! Realm()
         if let expense = self.expense {
             try! realm.write {
             realm.delete(expense)
         }
         // crashes during load
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToExpensesTable", sender: self) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you retaining a reference to `expense` in `DetailViewController`? After deleting the object make sure to clear out any references to it.

Comment: jervine10, you are the man! It's not the tableViewController that's crashing, it's the detailView since it's retaining a reference. If you write you comment as an answer I can give you credits for this one. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you aren't retaining any references to the deleted `Expense` object. After deleting the object clear out any reference you may have in `DetailViewController`, also make sure it isn't in an array somewhere that you might access it again.